# How to do redirection for a website in DNS

Tags: networking, dns, website, redirection, url

I have a requirement to configure redirection of a website

Both are a secure website
Old URL www.abc.com
New URL www.123.com

Whichever request comes in for new website  --> www.123.com should be redirected to existing website www.abc.com

Later maybe we will completely migrate to www.123.com but now I just need redirection to be done.

I have some question to implement this change in Infra level
Can we just add an alias in DNS and achieve redirection 
Do we need to change any network routing, firewall, GTM, LTM, etc
Do we need an SSL certificate for new URL 
Also please share some real-time ideas which you have already implemented

I appreciate your quick help on this topic. Please let me know if you need more inputs to understand the requirement.

Comment: DNS can point one domain to the location of the new server, but DNS cannot do redirects alone. So you would need to setup the DNS to point to the new location, and on there, setup something that does the actual redirect.

Answer (score 1):

If we talk about local servers, then we talk about PTR entry's, those are Pointer entrys which points, as the name already states, to the IP-Address of your wish.

If we talk about domain and website hosting, you need a CNAME that points towards an A-Record already existing as an entry. If you have an A-Record that points to the specific IP-Address then you are good to go, else you need to setup an A-Record which points to the specific IP-Address where www.123.com site is hosted an set the TTL.

In case you wish to use subdomains later with www.123.com, as example remote.123.com or autodiscover.123.com or any other subdomain, the I would recomend a wildcard certificate, which you can use then for *.123.com and anything behind.

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect using cNAME record in your DNS settings (www.123.com). You can later verify your DNS settings by websites like https://intodns.com https://cutewebstats.com etc.